# I am using IIS to run my PHP website although the links that I click on do not work and give me a 404.0 error,

Tags: php, url

Iknow the links work because i am also using VS code PHP server and everything works, please can anyone help? thanks.

This is the error i get:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:
Create the content on the Web server.
Review the browser URL.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    php-7.4.4RC1
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://zane.earth:80/main/communitypage/community.php
Physical Path      C:\zane.earth\main\homepage\main\communitypage\community.php
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

More Information:
This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again.
View more information »

Comment: This question is impossible to answer with the current level of detail provided. Are you sure you've uploaded your PHP files to the correct directory on the IIS server?

Answer (score 0):

No worries i figured it out now, i had to install PHP manager